# C++: Overloading operators. Curious type-transform operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I know, that C++ has operators, that i *shouldn't* overload.

operator '.' is one of these operators that i *can't* overload.

but, for best knowledge, does this overloading is bad?

I think, that it is really bad.
But i don't need to know, if i have object or pointer to object.
However, this is funny and dangerous

```
class A {
     public:
           get_int(){ return a } 
           A(){ a=1 }
           operator A*(){ return this }
     private: int a;
};
int main(){
    A a;
    A* c = a;
    //here, c->get_int() will return 1
}
```

Comment: does this overloading is bad? and for what reason, please. i only see a merging of too meanings like `object` and `pounter-to-object` and their accessability

Comment: +1 for "However, this is funny and dangerous", even though I have no idea what your problem is.

Comment: so it isnt a pointer of type A anymore?

Comment: People use this to implement "Smart pointers" sometimes. C++ is a crazy language...

Comment: @WoodrowDouglass: It's a bad idea to make smart pointers implicitly convertible to raw pointers; it would be very easy to accidentally hold on to a dangling pointer. Usually, smart pointers just overload the dereference operators `*` and `->`, and provide an explicit conversion function like `get()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to overload the indirection operator `->` to allow universal `x->foo()` syntax, irrespective of whether `x` is a pointer or not:

```
T * T::operator->() { return this; }
```

Usage:

```
T x, * p = &x;
p->foo(); // OK as usual
x->foo(); // also OK, weirdly
```

---

Example:

```
#include <cstdio>
struct Foo
{
    void foo() { std::puts("Boo"); }
    Foo * operator->() { return this; }
};

int main() { Foo x, * p = &x; p->foo(); x->foo(); }
```

Comment: Wouldn't the -> operater return a reference, not a pointer? so `T & T::operator->()`

Comment: @WoodrowDouglass: `operator->()` can return anything, as long as it is either a raw pointer or something to which you can apply `operator->()` again. So it cannot return a reference.